# Cannot retrieve data from AssyncStorage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I am using the AssyncStorage package from `@react-native-community/async-storage` and having a big problem when retrieving the stored data.

I don't know how to parse these Promisse results.

The fun fact is that if I `console.log(value)` inside the if statement, it shows the correct text, but it is returning the Promisse.

This is my function:

```
const getData = async (key: string) => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)

      if(value !== null) {
        return value
      }
    } catch(e) {
      TriggerAlert(I18n.t('error.readError') + e)
    }
  }
```

This is how I am calling the function

```
console.log(getData('@key'))
```

This is the output that I'm getting:

```
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}
```

Comment: your "getData" function also becomes asynchronous

Comment: try to await getData. console.log(await getData(...))

Comment: @WilsonPena it kinda works. When I type it gives me this error:

'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.

and if change my page to:
const Page = () => { ... code .... }

It crashes it

Comment: you have to make the function in which you call getData as async. Or else you can't use the await

Comment: @WilsonPena IT WORKED! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The below is correct, the way you extract the data :

```
const getData = async (key: string) => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)

      if(value !== null) {
        return value
      }
    } catch(e) {
      TriggerAlert(I18n.t('error.readError') + e)
    }
  }
```

Only thing you want to change is the function call place, since `getData` is an async func , it will return promise , hence you want to wait until the promises either resolves or rejects.

So you can do via ,

```
let myFunction = async() => {

  console.log(await getData('@key'))
}
```

hope it helps. feel free for doubts